# I have a few questions about frame repair, seat adjustments, and rims.

Tags: road-bike, rims, seatpost

```
                   My bike is a Trek 1100 Aluminum Frame
```

1. My bike has a few dings and scratched in the frame, and I want to get rid of them. So I was thinking I could get a powder coat or something to get a new paint job on there. I want to cover up the dings, but also get a new color on there like  bright green. Can I do that? If so would they go over the label and somehow out one back on or would they not put one back on? What is the price for that kind of thing too?
2. I was looking at some new colorful rims, and some said "single speed". What does that mean on a rim?
3. My bike is a Trek 1100 aluminum frame, so many of the adjustments are hex wrenches/Allan wrenches. The seat is also that way. So my question is, can I somehow put the modern seat adjuster on it? Like fit the clamp on there in a way it would stay, or is the seat post a little too small to do that?

Comment: Best to ask this as three separate questions. 
Several previous questions ask about painting a bike -e.g. [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4183/diy-painting-a-bike-frame-is-it-possible). Single speed means no gears, if you need to ask, they are not for you. Yes you can get a quick release for your seat post

Comment: Hex keys are perfectly modern for seat adjustment too. As for (1), it will cost more than the bike is worth since aluminum requires a good amount of work to prepare (i.e. not just sandblasting or sanding).

Comment: Regarding a seat clamp - post a picture of your bike, but from the Trek's I have looked it you can't use a collar. You may be able to replace the clamp bolt with a Cam lever of you can get the right length and thread. Otherwise just carry a hex key.

Comment: More likely on a rim "single speed" means "no brakes", it's important to check.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is possible to powder coat a frame.  They most likely wouldn't put new decals on.  You can usually find replacement decals online, shouldn't be too hard.  The powder coating process is a bit involved, and probably will not be cost-effective.  But if you want to spend the money, it's definitely possible.
2. First, let's get this right.  You're looking at "wheels", not "rims".  Sorry to be pedantic, but the terminology does matter here.  Single speed means what it says.  It has spacing/cassette body/freewheel threads for a single speed set-up.  Sometimes this can be adjusted(at great effort) to work for multi-speed systems, but more often it can't.
3. Had a hard time following this at first.  I think you're talking about a seatpost clamp.  First, there's nothing "classic" about one that takes an allen wrench.  Those are a bit more secure(if your bike is locked up somewhere, people will be less likely to walk up and steal your seat), and road bikers tend to change their seat height less frequently.  There are Quick Release options available for most sizes, as long as the clamp isn't integrated into the frame.