# How do I remove paint from my bike

Tags: paint

I have a shimona, I wanted to take all the paint off and paint it a color I want, but I can’t take the paint off, I’ve tried a sander, but it takes soooo long is there. Quicker way? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to strip the paint from a bike yourself?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20600/how-to-strip-the-paint-from-a-bike-yourself)

Comment: Aside, "shimona" is a chinese knockoff name for "shimano" components, and is not a brand or model of bike.

Answer (score 1):

Refinishing anything requires a great deal of work to get even an adequate result.  There is no substitute for elbow grease, and that is the chief ingredient to a project like refinishing a bike.

That said, there are several chemical options available that work more or less by softening and blistering the old paint which then can be scraped off with a plastic tool and/or various bristle brushes.  One such product is made by Rust-Oleum (a popular spray paint manufacturer). [Aircraft Remover](https://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/auto/removers-and-chemicals/aircraft-remover) is a chemical paint remover that is safe for all metals. After spraying or brushing it on, one lets the product work for up to an hour or more.  The old paint liquefies, bubbles up and can be scraped off. There are other similar products such as Klean Strip's [Aircraft Paint Remover](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/aircraft-aircraftremover-qt-qar2000/12072931-P).  I'm not sure why the companies choose to include "Airplane" or "Aircraft" in their labeling.

Obviously, you want to follow the directions on the label and adhere to the precautions.  Some of the chemicals are carcinogenic and very irritating to skin, eyes and lungs. Personal protective equipment is necessary.

Another option to refinish a bicycle is to leave the current paint in place.  Prep the surface by thorough washing to remove all traces of dirt and oil. Chips, scratches and other blemishes can be sanded smooth or at least the area "feathered," meaning to make the sharp edges of the chip or scratch smoother and blend the surrounding paint to the level of the ding's depth. Then the entire surface should be dulled with steel wool or fine sand paper. This removes any gloss of the old paint which can be an obstacle to new paint sticking. After a final wash with mineral spirits or alcohol, the frame will be ready for coating.

In either case, it's a good idea to use a primer that's compatible with the finish coat. It's best to use the same brand of primer as the finish coat.  Best results will come by way of applying the paint in aerosol form (using a sprayer or even via a spray paint can), as opposed to a brush. Applying multiple thin coats is a better technique than trying to get it on thick in one or two coats. You may choose to wet sand between coats to further smooth out any imperfections in the finish.

Whatever methods and products you chose to use the best results come from meticulous prepping of the surface.

A final thought would be to look into powder coating your frame.  This method utilizes electrostatic charge to coat the metal with a fine powder. The work piece is then baked in an oven, the powder melts into a very durable, smooth finish.  There are as many powder coat colors as there are paint colors, and one can choose various finishes as well (gloss, flat, metal flake...). There's even a technique where the finish appears as different colors depending on an observer's perspective and the properties of the reflected light reaching a given perspective.